# Unable to do ./configure during emacs installation

Tags: installation, emacs

I want to install emacs on my XUBUNTU 12.04. So I downloaded the emacs.tar.gz file.

I did **tar zxf emacs_x.x.x** to extract it to a folder.

Then **cd emacs/**

Then I tried to **./configure**. This is not working.

I'm using XUBUNTU 12.04 fresh installation. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What's the output of `./configure`?

Comment: Is there a special reason you're trying to compile it yourself from source code? Why not install it via Ubuntu's package management system? `sudo apt-get install emacs`

Comment: I don't have internet connectivity

Answer (score 0):

Probaly You need to run

```
./autogen.sh
```

before that. Have You read `README`?